# How do you pass two variables over a pipe in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, parameters, pipe

A program I want to run a program that accepts two inputs, however the inputs must be unzipped first.  The problem is the files are so large that unzipping them is not a good solution, so I need to unzip just the input.  For example:

```
gunzip myfile.gz | runprog > hurray.txt
```

That's a perfectly fine thing, but the program I want to run requires two inputs, both of which must be unzipped.  So

```
gunzip file1.gz

gunzip file2.gz

runprog -1 file1_unzipped -2 file2_unzipped
```

What I need is some way to unzip the files and pass them over a pipe, I imagine something like this:

```
gunzip f1.gz, f2.gz | runprog -1 f1_input -2 f2_input
```

Is this double?  Is there any way to unzip two files and pass the output across the pipe?

Comment: Try https://superuser.com/questions/201724/multiple-standard-input-how

Comment: If you want to send two files, unzipped, one after the other to the `stdin` of your program `zcat 1.gz 2.gz | yourProgram`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU `gunzip` has a `--stdout` option (aka. `-c`), for just this purpose, and there's also `zcat` as @slim pointed out. The resulting output *will* be concatenated into a single stream though, because that's [how pipes work](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution). One way you can get around this would be to create two input streams and handle them separately in `runprog`. For example, here's how you would make the first file input stream 8, and the second input stream 9:

```
runprog 8< <(zcat f1.gz) 9< <(zcat f2.gz)
```

Another alternative is to pass two file descriptors as *parameters* to the command:

```
runprog <(zcat f1.gz) <(zcat f2.gz)
```

The two arguments can now be treated just like two file arguments.

Comment: Or just invoke it as `zcat`

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm going to try these out and will post the success or failure!  I appreciate your response!

Answer (score 0):

Your program should understand there are two input from the zip files, you should have a delimiter in between two files.

When your program gets the delimiter, you should able to split the input into two parts. As the pipe may get your both input files in one buffer itself.